# Pyrogram client starts with error (sqlite)

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have a problem with starting pyrogram Client.

I've created an app in https://my.telegram.org/ and copied creds from there. 
 Now im starting client with:

```
from pyrogram import Client


client = Client(
    "occasion",
    api_id=os.environ.get('TG_API_ID'), 
    api_hash=os.environ.get('TG_API_HASH')
)

client.start()
client.send_message('me', 'some_message_text')
client.stop()
```

And it raises an error at the string `client.start()`

And error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\occasion-back-UNW6TZnG-py3.10\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\occasion-back-UNW6TZnG-py3.10\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 58, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\occasion-back-UNW6TZnG-py3.10\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\auth\connect.py", line 40, in connect
    await self.load_session()
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\occasion-back-UNW6TZnG-py3.10\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py", line 564, in load_session
    await self.storage.open()
  File "C:\Users\Artur_Epremian\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\occasion-back-UNW6TZnG-py3.10\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\storage\file_storage.py", line 58, in open
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(str(path), timeout=1, check_same_thread=False)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Can you please help me to find what is a reason?

Comment: I bet that at least one of these env vars is empty or just wrong

Comment: what coult it be?
All the creds are right. And it ran right without pyrogram with just tg api

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that I did it inside the app (django) before I started a session. So if you see this problem you should start a session manually (from terminal, python console, etc.) with your creds:

```
client = Client('name', api_id='', api_hash='')
client.start()  # here it will ask you to enter your phone number and confirmation code
client.export_session_string() 

# ->  and here you will get a string, save it in credentials too

client.stop()
```

And after you saved the session string you can run your app, you just have to pass parameter `session_string` in Client

```
client = Client(
    "occasion",
    api_id=os.environ.get('TG_API_ID'), 
    api_hash=os.environ.get('TG_API_HASH'),
    session_string=os.environ.get('TG_SESSION_STRING')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

start and stop methods are asynchronous. Try using the `with` statement:

```
from pyrogram import Client

client = Client(
    "occasion",
    api_id=os.environ.get('TG_API_ID'), 
    api_hash=os.environ.get('TG_API_HASH')
)

with client:
  client.send_message('me', 'some_message_text')
```